# Keyword association and tagging of video/image/HTML/etc. as a video editing database

Tags: linux, open-source, file-management, information-management, knowledge-base

I have many video clips, images and webpages (HTML) saved that I would like to use for writing articles and editing videos.

I’m trying to organize all of this so I can quickly find what I am looking for. To this end I need a (open source) program for Linux that can index any type of file according to parameters and keywords that I assign to it. The simpler the better.

Comment: Do you want a database type thing, or a file manager with these features?

Comment: I assume a file manager with these features will be sufficient, but any recommendations are welcome. I think it's obvious what I would like to do. I can give another example:

Say I have several .htm files saved from rt.com/news. To some of the files I've assigned the tag "Middle East" (among other tags). So when I am looking for all the news related to "Middle East", I quickly see a list of the files with that tag. This functionality needs to be extended to different file types - pictures, video, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nautilus (the file manager on Gnome) has this functionality already, it's called 'tracker'. You can tag files either by right-clicking on the file you want to tag, and going to the 'tags' tab. You can then search for files with that tag by running the (graphical) programme `tracker-needle`. There's not a lot of comprehensive information on tracker out there, but a good starting place may be here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker